# ChkTeX fails with nested math mode

Tags: math-mode, chktex

MWE:

```latex
\begin{align}
    \begin{array} {l}
        abc
    \end{array} \\
    3 - 2 = 1
    \pi
\end{align}
```

ChkTeX detects "Wrong length of dash" in `3 - 2 = 1` and "Command terminated with space" in `\pi`. Both warnings are wrong, because we are still inside an `align` environment, hence math mode is still on.

This error is persistent with other outer mathematical environments as `flalign`, `gather`, `multline`.

Am I doing something wrong here, or should I write a bug report to ChkTeX?

Comment: @egreg sorry, made a mistake. Fixed it now and double-checked. LaTeX compiles if there is an array inside align (or something else), but ChkTeX gives the same errors

Comment: This indeed seems like a bug, from a quick look in the source code of ChkTeX it looks like the status for being in math environment is boolean, so `\end{array}` switches math mode off and the fact that it is nested inside another math environment is not taken into account by ChkTeX. You could try filing a bug report at https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=chktex, the repository seems reasonably active (last commit a few weeks ago).